# int object is not iterable while trying to sum the digits of a number?

Tags: python, loops, integer

I have this code:

```
inp = int(input("Enter a number:"))

for i in inp:
    n = n + i;
    print (n)
```

but it throws an error: `'int' object is not iterable`

I wanted to find out the total by adding each digit, for eg, 110. 1 + 1 + 0 = 2. How do I do that?

Comment: If you're putting the digits together then it would be 110. I'm not sure where 11 came from.

Comment: @Trent: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939953/sum-the-digits-of-a-number-python

Comment: Relevant: [What are iterator, iterable and iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration) (specifically the "iterable" part).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First, lose that call to `int` - you're converting a string of characters to an integer, which isn't what you want (you want to treat each character as its own number). Change:

```
inp = int(input("Enter a number:"))
```

to:

```
inp = input("Enter a number:")
```

Now that `inp` is a string of digits, you can loop over it, digit by digit.

Next, assign some initial value to `n` -- as you code stands right now, you'll get a `NameError` since you never initialize it.  Presumably you want `n = 0` before the `for` loop.

Next, consider the difference between a character and an integer again.  You now have:

```
n = n + i;
```

which, besides the unnecessary semicolon (Python is an indentation-based syntax), is trying to sum the **character** i to the  **integer** n -- that won't work!  So, **this** becomes

```
n = n + int(i)
```

to turn character `'7'` into integer `7`, and so forth.

Answer (score 13):

maybe you're trying to

```
for i in range(inp)
```

This will print your input value (inp) times, to print it only once, follow:
for i in range(inp - inp + 1 )
print(i)

I just had this error because I wasn't using range()

Comment: How will that solve the problem? OP wants to iterate over the digits of the number, not to iterate `number` times...

Answer (score 7):

try:

```
for i in str(inp):
```

That will iterate over the characters in the string representation. Once you have each character you can use it like a separate number.

Comment: Hmm..it says TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: convert back to an int when adding?

Comment: Well when you go to add it to an integer, it is now a string. So in that case you could say int(i) + n or whatever it is.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you want to process the string representing the number, iterating over the digits, not the number itself (which is an abstract entity that could be written differently, like "CX" in Roman numerals or "0x6e" hexadecimal (both for 110) or whatever).

Therefore:

```
inp = input('Enter a number:')

n = 0
for digit in inp:
     n = n + int(digit)
     print(n)
```

Note that the `n = 0` is required (someplace before entry into the loop). You can't take the value of a variable which doesn't exist (and the right hand side of `n = n + int(digit)` takes the value of `n`). And if `n` does exist at that point, it might hold something completely unrelated to your present needs, leading to unexpected behaviour; you need to guard against that.

This solution makes no attempt to ensure that the input provided by the user is actually a number. I'll leave this problem for you to think about (hint: all that you need is there in [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/)).

Comment: This would work, great, I would suggest making it a function if the op as the knowledge with inp being a global variable and keeping n local so it reset back to zero when done and called again

Answer (score 3):

Side note: if you want to get the sum of all digits, you can simply do

```
print sum(int(digit) for digit in raw_input('Enter a number:'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`for .. in` statements expect you to use a type that has an iterator defined.   A simple int type does not have an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

As ghills had already mentioned

```
inp = int(input("Enter a number:"))

n = 0
for i in str(inp):
    n = n + int(i);
    print n
```

When you are looping through something, keyword is "IN", just always think of it as a list of something. You cannot loop through a plain integer. Therefore, it is not iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Take your input and make sure it's a string so that it's iterable.

Then perform a list comprehension and change each value back to a number.

Now, you can do the sum of all the numbers if you want:

```
inp = [int(i) for i in str(input("Enter a number:"))]
print sum(inp)
```

Or, if you really want to see the output while it's executing:

```
def printadd(x,y):
    print x+y
    return x+y

inp = [int(i) for i in str(input("Enter a number:"))]
reduce(printadd,inp)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer to OP-s question ("I wanted to find out the total by adding each digit, for eg, 110. 1 + 1 + 0 = 2. How do I do that?") is to use built-in function [divmod()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod)

```
num = int(input('Enter a number: ')
nums_sum = 0

while num:
    num, reminder = divmod(num, 10)
    nums_sum += reminder
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to change 
`for i in inp:`
into
`for i in range(1,inp):`
Iteration doesn't work with a single int. Instead, you need provide a range for it to run.

Comment: How will that solve the problem? OP wants to iterate over the digits of the number, not to iterate `number` times...

Answer (score -1):

Don't make it a `int()`, but make it a `range()` will solve this problem.

```
inp = range(input("Enter a number: "))
```

Comment: How will that solve the problem? OP wants to iterate over the digits of the number, not to iterate `number` times...