# Adding up the sum of digits

Tags: python, sum

I need to make a program that the user will enter in any number and then try guess the sum of those digits.

How do i sum up the digits and then compare then to his guess?

I tried this:

```
userNum = raw_input("Please enter a number:\n")

userGuess = raw_input("The digits sum is:\n")

if sum(userNum, userGuess):
    print"Your answer is True"
else:
    print "Your answer is False"
```

and it didnt work

Comment: sum with `sum` and compare with `==`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a code factory, please post your attempts, and ask your problems.

Comment: One line: `print('ok' if sum(map(int, input('Enter number: '))) == int(input('Enter aum: ')) else 'wrong')` (Python 3)

Comment: What error did you get? I would assume it's a `ValueError`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are new to Python and you've read the basics you would use control flow statements to compare the sum and the guess.

Not sure if this is 100% correct, feel free to edit, but it works. Coded it according to his(assuming) beginner level. This is assuming you've studied **methods, while loops, raw_input, and control flow statements**. Yes there are easier ways as mentioned in the comments but i doubt he's studied `map` Here's the code;

```
def sum_digits(n):
    s = 0
    while n:
        s += n % 10
        n /= 10
    return s
sum_digits(mynumber)
mynumber = int(raw_input("Enter a number, ")) 

userguess = int(raw_input("Guess the digit sum: "))
if sum_digits(mynumber) == userguess:
    print "Correct"
else:
    print "Wrong"
```

Credit to this answer for the method.

[Digit sum method in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939953/sum-the-digits-of-a-number-python)

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems here :

- `raw_input()` doesn't return an integer, it returns a string. You can't add strings and get an int. You need to find a way to convert your strings to integers, THEN add them.
- You are using `sum()` while using `+` whould be enough.

Try again, and come back with your results. Don't forget to include error messages and what you think happened.

Answer (score 2):

the python code is :

```
def digit_sum(n):
  string = str(n)
  total = 0
  for value in string:
      total += int(value)
  return total
```

and the code doesnot use the API:

```
def digit_sum1(n):
  total=0
  m=0
  while n:
      m=n%10
      total+=m
      n=(n-m)/10    
return total
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly you neet to use something such as `int(raw_input("Please enter a number:\n"))` so the input returns an integer.
2. Rather than using sum, you can just use + to get the sum of two *integers*. This will work now that your input is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically I would use a generator function for this

It will iterate over the string you get via `raw_input('...')` and create a list of the single integers

This list can then be summed up using `sum`

The generator would look like this:

```
sum([ int(num) for num in str(raw_input('Please enter a number:\n')) ])
```

Generators create lists (hence the list-brackets) of the elements prior to the for statement, so you could also take the double using:

```
[ 2 * int(num) for num in str(raw_input('Please enter a number:\n')) ]
```

`[ int(num) for num in str(123) ]` would result in `[1,2,3]`

but,

`[ 2 * int(num) for num in str(123) ]` would result in `[2,4,6]`