# How can I Keep the following program running until it becomes a single digit number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a program that can calculate the sum of an integer as well as count its digits . It will keep doing this until it becomes a one digit number.

For example, if I input 453 then its sum will be 12 and digit 3. 
Then it will calculate the sum of `12=1+2=3` it will keep doing this until it becomes one digit. I did the first part but i could not able to run it continuously using While . any help will be appreciated.

```
def main():

    Sum = 0
    m = 0
    n = input("Please enter an interger: ")
    numList = list(n)
    count = len(numList)
    for i in numList:
        m = int(i)
        Sum = m+Sum

    print(Sum)
    print(count)

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the most efficient way, but it doesn't matter much here; to me, this is a problem to elegantly solve by recursion :)

```
def sum_digits(n):
    n = str(n)
    if int(n) < 10:
        return n
    else:
        count = 0
        for c in n:
            count += int(c)
    return sum_digits(count)

print sum_digits(123456789) # --> 9  # a string
```

A little harder to read:

```
def sum_digits2(n):
    if n < 10:
        return n
    else:
        return sum_digits2(sum(int(c) for c in str(n))) # this one returns an int
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of tricky things to watch out for. Hopefully this code gets you going in the right direction. You need to have a conditional for while on the number of digits remaining in your sum. The other thing is that you need to covert back and forth between `strings` and `int`s. I have fixed the `while` loop here, but the `string` <-> `int` problem remains. Good luck!

```
def main():

    count = 9999
    Sum = 0
    m = 0
    n = input("Please enter an integer: ")
    numList = list(n)
    while count > 1:
        count = len(numList)
        for i in numList:
            m = int(i)
            Sum = m+Sum

        print(Sum)
        print(count)
        # The following needs to be filled in.
        numlist = ???

main()
```

Comment: This is not correct. I ran it . It never stops .by the way why u set count=0 primarily

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without repeated string parsing:

```
import math

x = 105 # or get from int(input(...))
count = 1 + int(math.log10(x))

while x >= 10:
    sum = 0
    for i in xrange(count):
        sum += x % 10
        x /= 10
    x = sum
```

At the end, x will be a single-digit number as described, and count is the number of original digits.

Comment: Must use `x //= 10` in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give credit to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939953/sum-the-digits-of-a-number-python) for a succinct way to sum up digits of a number, and the answers above for giving you some insight to the solution.

Here is the code I wrote, with functions and all. Ideally you should be able to reuse functions, and here the function digit_sum(input_number) is being used over and over until the size of the return value (ie: length, if sum_of_digits is read as a string) is 1. Now you can use the while loop to keep checking till the size is what you want, and then abort.

```
def digit_sum(input_number):
    return sum(int(digit) for digit in str(input_number))
input_number = input("Please enter a number: ")
sum_of_digits = digit_sum(input_number)
while(len(str(sum_of_digits)) > 1):
    sum_of_digits = digit_sum(input_number)
    output = 'Sum of digits of ' + str(input_number) + ' is ' + str(sum_of_digits)
    print output
    input_number = sum_of_digits
```

Answer (score 0):

this is using recursive functions

```
def sumo(n):
    sumof = 0

    while n > 0: 
        r = n%10 #last digit
        n = n/10 # quotient
        sumof += r #add to sum

    if sumof/10 == 0: # if no of digits in sum is only 1, then return
        return sumof

    elif sumof/10 > 0: #else call the function on the sumof
        sumo(sumof)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the first temptation would be to write

```
while x > 9:
    x = sum(map(int, str(x)))
```

that literally means "until there is only one digit replace x by the sum of its digits".

From a performance point of view however one should note that computing the digits of a number is a complex operation because Python (and computers in general) store numbers in binary form and each digit in theory requires a modulo 10 operation to be extracted.

Thus if the input is not a string to begin with you can reduce the number of computations noting that if we're interested in the final sum (and not in the result of intermediate passes) it doesn't really matter the order in which the digits are summed, therefore one could compute the result directly, without converting the number to string first and at each "pass"

```
while x > 9:
    x = x // 10 + x % 10
```

this costs, from a mathematical point of view, about the same of just converting a number to string.

Moreover instead of working out just one digit however one could also works in bigger chunks, still using maths and not doing the conversion to string, for example with

```
while x > 99999999:
    x = x // 100000000 + x % 100000000
while x > 9999:
    x = x // 10000 + x % 10000
while x > 99:
    x = x // 100 + x % 100
while x > 9:
    x = x // 10 + x % 10
```

The first loop works 8 digits at a time, the second 4 at a time, the third two and the last works one digit at a time. Also it could make sense to convert the intermediate levels to `if` instead of `while` because most often after processing `n` digits at a time the result will have `n` or less digits, leaving while loops only for first and last phases.

Note that however the computation at this point is so fast that Python general overhead becomes the most important part and thus not much more can be gained.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function to find the sum and keep updating the argument to be the most recent sum until you hit one digit.

```
def splitSum(num):
    Sum = 0
    for i in str(num):
        m = int(i)
        Sum = Sum + m

    return str(Sum)

n = input("Please enter an integer: ")
count = 0
while count != 1:
    Sum = splitSum(n)
    count = len(Sum)
    print(Sum)
    print(count)
    n = Sum
```