# sum of a number's digits using a built-in function

Tags: python

I have written a Python function that takes an integer as input and returns the sum of all that number's digits:

```
def digit_sum(n):
    n_lst = list( str(n) )
    n_sum = 0
    for i in range( len(n_lst) ):
        n_sum += int( n_lst[i] )
    return n_sum

print( digit_sum(1234) )            # 10
```

Now I wonder if there is a more concise way of doing this perhaps, using a built-in function or list comprehensions?

Comment: what if a user entered `'123hello456!-7'` ?

Comment: Good point, thanks, but as a novice, I am assuming the input is a positive integer for the time being.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: Why should that be any different than if the user entered 'xyz'?

Comment: @ScottHunter, you'll get an error using your code with input such as `'xyz123'`

Comment: I believe it is answered in more details here --
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939953/sum-the-digits-of-a-number-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer `sum(map(int, str(n)))`.

Comment: Ever since I read http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196 I am kind of reluctant to use `map`. Apart from that, the code will behave consistently between Py 2 and 3 if I use LC and GE.

Comment: @thefourtheye - That guy doesn't know anything about Python! =P Joking aside, `map` is still fine to use (as far as clarity) when you're mapping to a preexisting built-in. It's also slightly faster. And you should use Python 3 exclusively anyway. :)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I know that nothing wrong in using it, but since the dictator has spoken against it, it kind of feels like a taboo using it :D

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
sum( [int(x) for x in list(str(n))] )
```

Comment: Converting the string to a list is not necessary, as we can directly iterate the string itself. And, creating a list comprehension is not necessary, as `sum` can work with one value at a time, it doesn't need the entire list to process.

Comment: @thefourtheye: Sure; I was trying to show how `sum` and a list comprehension could be used, and figured it would be clearer if the rest was closer to what the OP already understood.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the number to a string and then add the individual numbers, like this

```
sum(int(num) for num in str(n))
```

This uses a generator expression, and `sum` function iterates the generator expression to keep adding the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

While all the recent answers are good for "guaranteed" integer input, I'll leave here a sanitized approach(as an alternative) considering ***"raw"*** input:

```
import re

def digit_sum(sequence):
    return sum(int(d) for d in re.findall('\d', sequence))    

print(digit_sum(input("enter some digits"))) 

print(digit_sum("123werwer13!-"))  # 10
print(digit_sum("abbc"))           # 0
```

`re.findall('\d', sequence)` - will find all numbers within an input sequence

Comment: Many thanks. This is genius! (Since I was looking for a one-liner equivalent, I had to mark `sum(map(int, str(n)))` as the correct answer, but your is obviously a brilliant comprehensive solution...)