# Understanding this simple code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a total beginner in programming. My question is what actually this code does. I think it takes the whole division result from 10, and then calculates mod 10, and prints it. The `res` here I think is not a built-in command in Python, and is just a variable used here, but its value is zero.

Here's the code in question:

```
res=0
num=int(input("Enter a postive integer:  "))
while num > 0:
    res=res+(num % 10)
    num = num // 10
    print(res)
```

Comment: Did you run the code? [This looks similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939953/sum-the-digits-of-a-number-python#14940026)

Comment: It's a given code which is part of homework. I did run it, and that's what I think it does, but if that's true, how come the results can be greater than 9.

Comment: Because `res` is being added to

Comment: But isn't it set to be zero?

Comment: It is, *outside the loop*. It then gradually gets incremented.

Comment: Yes, initially... Look here ... `res=`**res +**`(num % 10)`

Comment: It sums the digits.

Comment: But how? I thought it gets the original "res" value (which is zero), and then it's added by the num % 10. So, how does it get greater than 9?

Sums the digits? But still I don't understand, if that's the case, is still should'nt be greaer than nine.

Comment: because res can have some initial value after the first loop.

Comment: You seem to not understand how loops work. Is your question correctly indented? You should see the print statement increasing the value

Comment: mod 10 is only applied to `num` not `res` so it can go above 9

Answer (score 0):

Try running this.

```
res=0
num=int(input("Enter a postive integer:  "))
while num > 0:
    print("res = {0} + {1}".format(res, num % 10))
    res = res + (num % 10)
    num = num // 10
print(res)
```

In words, `while num > 0`, the digits of `num` are summed from right-to-left.

`res` starts at 0, and increases each time over the loop.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand what it does. But I don't actually understand how it does that. I mean, which commnand here means "sums of all digits"? The "num // 10" in Python gives me the whole number result which is divised by ten, and "num % 10" gives me the remainder of the division number by ten. So what exactly here tells the program to sum up the digits?

Comment: `res` is an integer. `+` adds things. `res = res +` adds onto the existing `res` value and can be re-written as `res += `