# Creating a digital root function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I encounter a strange problem:

a digital root function is something looks like this:

```
digital_root(493193)
=> 4 + 9 + 3 + 1 + 9 + 3
=> 29 ...
=> 2 + 9
=> 11 ...
=> 1 + 1
=> 2
```

and my answer is:

```
def digital_root(n):
    k = 10
    while k > 9:
        k = reduce(lambda x,y: int(x)+int(y), list(str(n)))
    return k
```

I set k to 10 so that it will directly go in to the loop.
But the online judge says it costs too much time.

and I try another solution:

```
def digital_root(n):
    while n > 9:
        n = reduce(lambda x,y: int(x)+int(y), list(str(n)))
    return n
```

then the problem solved. I can figure out what's the difference between these two codes

By the way, I use the codewars online judge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

problem here is that you have an *infinite loop* and your first solution is not slow but just *wrong*

```
def digital_root(n):
    k = 10
    while k > 9:
        k = reduce(lambda x,y: int(x)+int(y), list(str(n)))
    return k
```

the first `reduce` gives 29. so `k > 9`, and it does it again, but since you're not reinjecting `k` but reusing `n`, you get `29` again.

the second solution is correct because it changes & reinjects `n` as long as it is greater than 9 (and doesn't enter in the loop if `n <= 9` because in that case digital root is the number itself).

Edit: for that particular case you don't need `reduce` at all. That code is clearer and probably faster:

```
def digital_root(n):
    while n > 9:
        n = sum(int(x) for x in str(n))
    return n
```

(sums all int-converted digits of `n` in a generator comprehension)

Comment: Probably could still be faster, though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939953/sum-the-digits-of-a-number-python

Comment: yes, converting to string is probably not the best thing to do with all the back & forth conversions, I could have thought of that...

Comment: Thank you all, actually this is faster 
`
def digital_root(n):
    return n%9 or n and 9
`

I saw this code on codewars, very clever!

Answer (score 1):

You can do, also, something like this example:

```
def reduce_root(num = 0):
    if isinstance(num, int):
        return [k for k in str(num)]
    else:
        raise Exception("input number must be an integer!")

def digital_root(num = 0):
    number = reduce_root(num)
    print("Number: {}".format(num))
    while True:
        if len(number) == 1:
            break
        else:
            print("=> {}".format(" + ".join(k for k in number)))
            s = sum(int(k) for k in number)
            print("=> {}".format(s))
            number = reduce_root(s)
```

Output:

```
digital_root(100245)

Number: 100245
=> 1 + 0 + 0 + 2 + 4 + 5
=> 12
=> 1 + 2
=> 3
```

Comment: I think the output was an example, not actually wanted :)

Comment: Maybe you're right. I think i should wait the OP answer. Then i can edit my answer. Thanks by the way for your comment.