# Sum of digit of random number

Tags: python-2.7

I'm a beginner on python and I want to know how can I sum digits for a random number between 1-10000
Print the number is easy:

```
from random import randint

x = randint(1, 10001)

print x
```

but how can I sum the number of digit of the outcome,
Thanks,

Comment: One of the many ways: convert to string, split into array, map to `int`, then `sum`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum the digits of a number - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939953/sum-the-digits-of-a-number-python)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will answer your question.Convert the number to string and parse digit by digit.

```
from random import randint
x = randint(1, 10001)
print x
sum = 0
for i in str(x):
    sum += int(i)
print sum
```