# Adding up a number to give a single number

Tags: python

```
print ('Welcome to BirthPath Calculator')

Day = input('Input you day of Birth (1-31): ')
Month = input('Input your month of birth (1-12): ')
Year = input ('Input your year of birth: ')

Day = int(Day)
Month = int(Month)
Year = int(Year)

Birthpath = Day + Month + Year
sum(Birthpath)

print ('This is your Birth Path: '+str(Birthpath))
```

I want the `Birthpath` to sum to a single number.
Let's assume that the value of the `Birthpath` is 2014, I want to sum it up to 2+0+1+4= 7.

Comment: Please, edit your question to add what problem do you have exactly.

Comment: I want the answer of the Birthpath= (2016) to sum up to a single number=(9)

Comment: Hey welome to SO, before asking a question try searching for a solution. Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939953/sum-the-digits-of-a-number-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to treat a string as a list. So if you make the total of the day+month+year into a string and then loop over that it that would work

```
print('Welcome to BirthPath Calculator')
day = int(input('Input you day of Birth (1-31): '))
month = int(input('Input your month of birth (1-12): '))
year = int(input('Input your year of birth: '))
total = day + month + year
birthpath = 0
for digit in str(total):
    birthpath += int(digit)
print('This is your Birth Path: ' + str(birthpath))
```

You can also use a list comprehension to make this a bit shorter.

```
print('Welcome to BirthPath Calculator')
day = int(input('Input you day of Birth (1-31): '))
month = int(input('Input your month of birth (1-12): '))
year = int(input('Input your year of birth: '))
total = day + month + year
birthpath = sum(int(digit) for digit in str(total))
print('This is your Birth Path: '+str(birthpath))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old classic problem to get a sum of digits of a number:

```
def sum_of_digits(number):
    sum = 0
    while number > 0:
      remainder = number % 10
      sum += remainder
      number //= 10
    return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple one liner will work!

```
Birthpath = 2014
sum(int(i) for i in str(Birthpath))
```