# I want to know how to limit recursion in range of length of string(in this function str(n))

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

```py
def sum_digits(n):
    
    if n < 10:
        return n
    else:
        return int(str(n)[len(str(n))-1]) + sum_digits(n - int(str(n)[len(str(n))-1]))

#TEST
print(sum_digits(22541))
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with your code?

Comment: To limit the recursions, you can do `sys.setrecursionlimit(limit)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum the digits of a number - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939953/sum-the-digits-of-a-number-python)

Comment: @xavc I guess this is a try to get into the famous Stack Overflow series "Things you should not do with recursion done recursively".

Answer (score 0):

A better way to calculate the sum of the digits of a number using recursion is

```
def sumOfDigits(n) :
    if n == 0 :
        return 0
    else :
        return n%10 + sumOfDigits(n//10)
```