# Keep getting TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, int

I keep getting this error:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.

My assignment that I need to (so you have some background on what I am trying to achieve) is this: "Write a program that will create 100 random integer numbers, both negative and positive between -10 and +10 (in a for loop) and then determine how many were positive and how many were negative. Finally, print out how many numbers were positive and how many numbers were negative."

```
import random

positive = 0
negative = 0

for number in random.randrange(-10,10):
    if number > 0:
        positive += 1
    else:
        negative += 1
print ("End")
```

That's my code so far. If anyone can help me using the above information and my error, that'd be great!

Comment: you are iterating over `number` which is why you are getting an error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [int object is not iterable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938227/int-object-is-not-iterable)

Comment: I looked at that link, and it does not help. If someone could answer me in detail, that'd be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.randrange(-10,10)` creates a single random integer, it does not automatically create `100` random integers. Hence when you try to do - `for number in random.randrange(-10,10):` - it errors out as you are trying to iterate over an integer which should not be possible.

I would suggest iterating over `range(100)` , and then taking `random.randrange(-10,10)` inside the loop. Example -

```
for _ in range(100):
    number = random.randrange(-10,10)
    if number > 0:
        positive += 1
    else:
        negative += 1
```

Comment: Thank you, I did this and it actually worked. Will give you the credit in a minute or so.

Answer (score 1):

[`random.randrange()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randrange) is a function that returns a single random number. Your code is erroring out because you are then trying to loop over that single number like it is iterable.

Instead, you want to generate a random number 100 separate times, so your for loop should instead look something like this:

```
for i in range(100):
    number = random.randrange(-10,10)
    # do stuff with number...
```

Answer (score 1):

`random.randrange(-10,10)` returns a random number in `range(-10,10)`, which is not iterable. `random.randrange(-10,10) for _ in range(100)` will do what you want. Also, you never print out the positive and negative counts.

Comment: Thank you, you got me on the right track like the other guy! Thanks again!