# TypeError("'int' object is not iterable", in my code in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, int, typeerror, iterable

I got an assignment in my CS class: to find pairs of numbers in a list, that add to a number *n*, that is given.
This is the code I wrote for it:

```
def pair (n, num_list):    
    """
    this function return the pairs of numbers that add to the value n.
    param: n: the value which the pairs need to add to.
    param: num_list: a list of numbers.
    return: a list of all the pairs that add to n.
    """    
    for i in num_list:
        for j in num_list:
            if i + j == n:
                return [i,j]
                continue
```

When I try to run it, I'm given the following message:

```
TypeError("'int' object is not iterable",)
```

What is the problem? I can't find a place in which I use a `list` obj as an `int`, or vice versa.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938227/int-object-is-not-iterable

Comment: Hi, I tried your function with >>> pair(4, [1,2,3])
[1, 3] and it works

Comment: 1). You're passing an integer instead of a list of numbers as the 2nd argument of `pair`. 2) But even if you _do_ call it properly your `pair` function will only return a list of the first pair it finds. You need to collect those pairs into a master list and return that list once you've tested every pair. 3). You code will test if a number in `num_list` pairs with itself, which may be ok. But it tests every other pair twice, which may not be ok.

Answer (score 0):

num_list must be iterable.

Your code return first pair, not all pairs.

Read about [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
[[i, j] for i in num_list for j in num_list if i + j == n]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your function like a list, you can yield the values instead of returning them:

```
def pair (n, num_list):       
    for i in num_list:
        for j in num_list:
            if i + j == n:
                yield i, j
```

More info here: https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/