# Into object is not iterable

Tags: python

I am writing a function of Python would like to sum all the number in a tuples but it.s get wrong after run

```
def sumall(*x):

   sm=0

   for i in len (x):
      sm= x[i] + sm

   print sm
```

It.s contain into object is not iterable error when I input

sumall (1,2,3)

Please help me

Comment: `for i in x` will do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [int object is not iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938227/int-object-is-not-iterable)

Answer (score 2):

```
def sumall(x):
   return sum(x)

sumall((1, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

As pydev answered, there is a builtin `sum` method which does exactly what you asked. So, you better use it. But if you are doing this code for exercise, you have few issues

```
def sumall(*x):
   sm=0
                      .<---- there shouldn't be space between len and (x) and range is required
   for i in range(len(x)):
      sm= x[i] + sm  <---- this can be converted to sm += x[i] which appends

   print sm
```

`len` is returning an `int` which isn't iterable. `range` on the other hand does.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the syntax of `for x in l` takes `l` as an iterable - `list`, `tuple`, etc.

The statement `len(x)` returns an integer, which isn't by any means an iterable.

You should simply loop over `x`.

```
def sumall(*x):
    sm=0

    for item in x:
        sm= item + sm

    print sm
```

However, in cases when you do need to loop by index (e.g. when your'e looping over two iterables at once) you can use `range()`, which returns a list of numbers (from 0 to the specified number) you can loop over.

```
def sumall(*x):
    sm=0

    for i in range(len(x)):
        sm= x[i] + sm

    print sm
```