# Python TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable, trying to append integers to list

Tags: python, int, typeerror

Can anyone help me figure out this error?

This is code for an encryption/decryption game.

```
import random
import itertools

"""Defines the alphabet list and number list used to make the dictionaries for encoding/decoding."""
alph = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
        'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
num = range(0, 26)

"""Creates the dictionaries used to encode/decode"""
alph_to_num = dict(zip(alph, num))
num_to_alph = dict(zip(num, alph))


def vigenere_encode(text):
    key = 'lemon'
    text = text.lower()
    k = itertools.cycle(key)
    key_list = []
    encoded_list = []
    i = 1
    while i <= len(text):
        key_list.append(next(k))
        i += 1
    num_list = [alph_to_num[s] if s in alph else s for s in text]
    num_key_list = [alph_to_num[s] for s in key_list]
    for num1, num2 in zip(num_list, num_key_list):
        if num1 in num:
            encoded_list.append(sum(num1, num2))
        else:
            encoded_list.append(num1)
    encoded_list = [num_to_alph[n % 26 + 1] if n in num else n for n in encoded_list]
    encoded_str = ""
    for i in encoded_list:
        encoded_str += i
    print('Your key is: ' + key)
    print('The encoded string is: ' + encoded_str)
```

Here is the error:

```
line 28, in vigenere_encode
    encoded_list.append(sum(num1, num2))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I had found a more optimal way of writing that section of code, namely:

```
encoded_list = list(map(sum, zip(num_list, num_key_list)))
```

but with that way of writing the code I wasn't sure how to allow for non-alphabet characters in the text to be encoded, and I would like a code format that allows me to write the `decode()` function without having to change a lot.

I am a relative beginner.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [int object is not iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938227/int-object-is-not-iterable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `sum` function takes an iterable and sum all values inside the iterable. You're trying to use it as `sum(num1, num2)` and that is not how it works.

If you just want to add two numbers together, use the `+` operator, as in: `num1 + num2`; The `sum()` function is for when you already have the numbers in some sort of iterable data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use `encoded_list.append(num1 + num2)` instead of `encoded_list.append(sum(num1, num2))`